# TypeScript: Filling an Object progressively to match a type/interface

Tags: typescript, properties, typing

In TypeScript, is there a way to progressively build an object to match a type or interface, without having the IDE (or the compiler?) complaining because not all expected attributes are here from the start?

Let me take an example. I have a list of fruits, and I will want to manipulate objects that assign values to each and every fruit.

```js
type Fruit = 'apple' | 'lemon' | 'melon';
type FruitMapToString = { [ key in Fruit ]: string; };

const FRUIT_DESCRIPTIONS: FruitMapToString = {
  apple: 'A basic fruit',
  lemon: 'An acidic fruit',
  melon: 'A refreshing fruit',
} as const;
```

This is in a file that might be modified to add new fruits. And I don't want the rest of my code to rely on the knowledge of what fruits exists, because I don't want to update it.

Now, I want a map from fruits to number (to count my fruits). And I want to use a type that implies that *all* fruits are covered:

```js
type FruitMapToNumber = { [ key in Fruit ]: number; };
```

So, I want to rely on `FRUIT_DESCRIPTIONS`'s key to initialize my object to: `{ apple: 0, lemon: 0, melon: 0 }`. But I can't find a way to do that without the IDE complaining at some point that some properties are lacking.

Typically I would like to do that:

```js
function makeFruitToNumberMap(): FruitMapToNumber {
  const map: FruitMapToNumber = {}; // ❌ Missing the properties 'apple' etc
  let fruit: Fruit;
  for ( fruit in FRUIT_DESCRIPTIONS ) {
    map[ fruit ] = 0;
  }
  return map;
}
```

But it doesn't work, because when initialized to `{}`, my map is lacking properties.

I also tried starting with a type where the keys are optional:

```js
  const map: { [ key in Fruit ]?: boolean; } = {};
```

But then the IDE complains at the `return` level, because “*`'number | undefined'` is not assignable to type `'number'`*”. (Even thought at the end of the functions, all fruits are assigned to `0`.)

I even tried this, even through I don't want to use that for readability:

```js
function makeFruitToNumberMap(): FruitMapToNumber {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys( FRUIT_DESCRIPTIONS ).map(
      ( fruit ) => [ fruit, 0 ]
    )
  );
}
```

Again, the IDE complains about missing properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be more convinient to use enum here for setting up primary types and use them for iterating:

```
enum Fruit {
  apple = "apple",
  lemon = "lemon",
  melon = "melon"
}
type TFruit = keyof typeof Fruit; //it's the same as your strings uion type

type FruitMapToNumber = { [key in Fruit]: number };
type FruitMapToString = { [key in Fruit]: string };
const FRUIT_DESCRIPTIONS: FruitMapToString = {
  [Fruit.apple]: "A basic fruit",
  [Fruit.lemon]: "An acidic fruit",
  [Fruit.melon]: "A refreshing fruit"
};
```

There's no way to create an object with already predefined fields. So, we can create it only by iterating. And here there're 2 unpleasant things:

- the 1st one as it's iterating creation we always start with an **empty** object and that means we have `Partial` type in the end.
- the 2d unpleasant thing here is that js doesn't allow us to
  pass which keys will be returned from `Object.keys` method, it always
  expects to return `string` keys.

  ```
  function makeFruitToNumberMap() {
    const keys = Object.keys(Fruit); // 2d issue: keys type is string[]
    const map = keys.reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: 0 }), {}); // 1st issue: original object is empty and we set values iteratively

    return map;
  }
  ```

So, to resolve it we can use **casting**

```
function makeFruitToNumberMap() {
  const keys = Object.keys(Fruit) as TFruit[];
  const map = keys.reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: 0 }), {});

  return map as FruitMapToNumber;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure I would use `enum` in my case due to the bulkiness of the code most probably in need to be updated. The map building also isn't the most readable, but it can be solved by creating once a general map-building function: `function makeFruitMap<T>( value: T ): { [key in Fruit]: T } { … }`. Anyway, type casting solved the general issue (see my answer without `enum`).

Answer (score 0):

Anastasiya Stanevich made me realize that what I was lacking is [***type assertion***](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/type-assertion), i.e., using `… as Type` to assert that my object was indeed, at this point, of the required type `Type`.

I should also be using **`Partial<Type>`** to type my “not yet completed” object.

Typically, in the sample case I provided:

```
function makeFruitToNumberMap(): FruitMapToNumber {
  const map: Partial<FruitMapToNumber> = {}; //  Partial
  let fruit: Fruit;
  for ( fruit in FRUIT_DESCRIPTIONS ) {
    map[ fruit ] = 0;
  }
  return map as FruitMapToNumber; //  Type assertion
}
```